# Dynamic Imports: Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dynamic-import

I have a React project that uses Webpack as a bundler, and I'm splitting my bundle into two chunks -- the main codebase `main.js`, and the vendor bundle `vendor.js`.

After building these bundles, `main.js` ends up being 45kb and `vendor.js` is 651kb.

One specific vendor library is 225kb and seems to be the worst offendor in the vendor imports.

I am importing this library in a page component at the top of the file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ModuleA, ModuleB } from 'heavyPackage'; // 225kb import

...

const Page = ({ setThing }) => {

...

};
```

To try and have this heavy import loaded in a separate bundle, I tried to instead import these modules using a dynamic import.

Inside the `Page` component, the modules weren't actually used until a particular function was called, so I tried to import the modules within that scope rather than at the top of the file:

```js
import React from 'react';

...

const Page = ({ setThing }) => {

  ...

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    const scopedPackage = await import('heavyPackage');
    const { moduleA, moduleB } = scopedPackage;

    // use moduleA & moduleB normally here
  };

};
```

For some reason I figured Webpack would intelligently pick up on what I'm trying to do here and separate this heavy package into its own chunk that is downloaded only when needed, but the resulting bundles were the same -- a `main.js` that was 45kb and a `vendor.js` that was 651kb. Is my line of thinking here correct and possibly my Webpack configuration is off, or am I thinking of dynamic imports in the wrong way?

**edit** I have Webpack configured to split the bundle using `splitChunks`. Here is how I have this configured:

```js
  optimization: {
    chunkIds: "named",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          chunks: "initial",
          maxInitialRequests: 5,
          minChunks: 2,
          minSize: 0,
        },
        vendor: {
          chunks: "initial",
          enforce: true,
          name: "vendor",
          priority: 10,
          test: /node_modules/,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: First, good way of thinking. Now let's see why it still brings it in the start. Can you debug your code and put a breakpoint at the first line of heavyPackage code? Maybe someone else also imports it without your knowledge (maybe a 3rd part library depends on it). Another thing that might happen is that you configured your webpack optimization rules as such that the maximum chunks that you allow webpack to generate is two. That's less common. I suggest to find the first import chain that brings this lazy package - I'll be surprise if its from your dynamic import.

Comment: Hi @RazRonen -- thanks for the insight. I'm using `splitChunks` in my Webpack config to split my bundle. I've updated the question to include this `splitChunks` setup. I need to research a bit more, but I think my `splitChunks` config is preventing this from working as I'm expecting?

Comment: Any news on this? All the answers involve a dynamically loaded component, but your questions was about a heavy package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update for React 18**: The code below is no longer required to split chunks/dynamically load components. Instead, you can use [React.lazy with Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense), which achieves similar results (this only works for **React components**, therefore any `node_module` imports would need to be imported within this dynamically loaded component):

> ```
> const ProfilePage = React.lazy(() => import('./ProfilePage')); // Lazy-loaded
>
> <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
>  <ProfilePage />
> </Suspense>
> ```

---

@Ernesto's answer offers one way of code splitting by using `react-loadable` with the `babel-dynamic-import` plugin, however, if your Webpack version is v4+ (and has a [custom Webpack config set to SplitChunks by all](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit/blob/master/config/optimization.js#L60-L61)), then you'll only need to use magic comments and a custom React component.

From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments):

> By adding [magic] comments to the import, we can do things such as name our chunk or select different modes. For a full list of these magic comments see the code below followed by an explanation of what these comments do.

> // Single target
>
> ```js
> import(
>  /* webpackChunkName: "my-chunk-name" */
>  /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
>  'module'
> );
> ```

> // Multiple possible targets
>
> ```js
> import(
>  /* webpackInclude: /\.json$/ */
>  /* webpackExclude: /\.noimport\.json$/ */
>  /* webpackChunkName: "my-chunk-name" */
>  /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
>  /* webpackPrefetch: true */
>  /* webpackPreload: true */
>  `./locale/${language}`
> );
> ```

Therefore, you can create a reusable `LazyLoad` component like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class LazyLoad extends Component {
  state = {
    Component: null,
    err: "",
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.importFile();

  componentWillUnmount = () => (this.cancelImport = true);

  cancelImport = false;

  importFile = async () => {
    try {
      const { default: file } = await import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
        /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
        `pages/${this.props.file}/index.js`
      );

      if (!this.cancelImport) this.setState({ Component: file });
    } catch (err) {
      if (!this.cancelImport) this.setState({ err: err.toString() });
      console.error(err.toString());
    }
  };

  render = () => {
    const { Component, err } = this.state;

    return Component ? (
      <Component {...this.props} />
    ) : err ? (
      <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{err}</p>
    ) : null;
  };
}

LazyLoad.propTypes = {
  file: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default file => props => <LazyLoad {...props} file={file} />;
```

Then in your routes, use `LazyLoad` and pass it the name of a file in your `pages` directory (eg `pages/"Home"/index.js`):

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LazyLoad from "../components/LazyLoad";

const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LazyLoad("Home")} />
    <Route component={LazyLoad("NotFound")} />
  </Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

On that note, `React.Lazy` and `React-Loadable` are alternatives to having a custom Webpack config or Webpack versions that don't support dynamic imports.

---

A working demo can be found [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit). Follow [installation](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit#installation) instructions, then you can run `yarn build` to see routes being split by their [name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXGmY.png).

Comment: Hi Matt -- thanks for this great answer. I still have a lot to learn about this, but your answer definitely helped. A lot of examples focus on dynamic imports at the route level. There are some examples where a vendor package is imported inside of a lazy loaded file, which is more or less what I'm trying to do.

Comment: For some reason, I haven't been able to get these examples to work, although it's helped me verbalize the desired scenario more, which is this: user navigates to site --> only the main bundle is downloaded and seen in the network tab --> user clicks button (or some such action) --> vendor chunk is downloaded and can be seen in the network tab.

Comment: I found this Webpack page on Lazy Loading that describes a very similar scenario, but even in their example, it looks like they moved the lodash import to be in the main bundle rather than in the chunk: https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/ .

Comment: In your example, I see that the chunks are split out, but it looked like they were all loaded into the network tab on page load when I checked (I had also been monkeying around with the code when I tried this out, so let me know if this is wrong -- might be user error).

Comment: I'm also making a huge assumption that the chunk being loaded in later on (and seeing this file loaded later in the network tab) means that performance will be increased, but maybe that actually doesn't matter. Maybe the point is that the main bundle should load in the most immediate user experience, and other chunks can also be loaded in at this time, but they do not block that immediate user experience. Anyway, thanks again for the answer. It helped a lot, and I'm gonna keep digging into this.

Comment: When in production, I only see these files being requested from the server when landing on the home page: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/3yCShEq.png). Then when landing on the not-found page: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/tyklUMb.png). Appears to be working as expected. That said, you could split up `vendors-main` into smaller chunks if they include chunks not being shared by all routes.

Comment: If you need to see a chunk distribution chart, then run `yarn analyze` to see what each chunk contains. For reference, it'll look something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/t7nCmCU.png).

Comment: Ah okay I'm seeing what you're talking about now. Thanks. This is a really nice starter kit.

Answer (score 2):

Oki then, look! you have yow webpack config with the `splitChunks` property, also you need to add a `chunkFilename` property in side of the `output` object from `webpack`.

If we take for example the one generated by CRA

```
      // The build folder.
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
      // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
      // In development, it does not produce real files.
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // TODO: remove this when upgrading to webpack 5
      futureEmitAssets: true,

      // THIS IS THE ONE I TALK ABOUT
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      // webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
      // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
      // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
      publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
      // Prevents conflicts when multiple webpack runtimes (from different apps)
      // are used on the same page.
      jsonpFunction: `webpackJsonp${appPackageJson.name}`,
      // this defaults to 'window', but by setting it to 'this' then
      // module chunks which are built will work in web workers as well.
      globalObject: 'this',
    },
```

Once you have that on yow webpack. next thing is to install a `npm i -D @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` and add it to your babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = api =>
...
return {
  presets: [
   .....
 ],
 plugins: [
....
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
....
 ]
}
```

then last thing `npm install react-loadable`
create a folder called: `containers`. in it place all the containers

[image]

inside index.js do some like:

[image]

The loadable object have two properties

```js
export const List = Loadable({
    loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "lists" */ "./list-constainer"),
    loading: Loading,
});
```

- loader: component to dynamically import
- loadinh: component to display until the dynamic component is loaded.

and for last on you Router set each loadable to a route.

```js
...
import { Lists, List, User } from "../../containers";
...
export function App (): React.ReactElement {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <SideNav>
                    <nav>SideNav</nav>
                </SideNav>
                <Main>
                    <Header>
                        <div>Header</div>
                        <div>son 2</div>
                    </Header>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={ROUTE_LISTS} component={Lists} />
                        <Route path={ROUTE_LISTS_ID_USERS} component={List} />
                        <Route path={ROUTE_LISTS_ID_USERS_ID} component={User} />
                        <Redirect from="*" to={ROUTE_LISTS} />
                    </Switch>
                </Main>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

so then when you bundle yow code we get some like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Ernesto. Why do you use react-loadable instead of React Lazy?

Comment: oh, I come from the old school my friend. I havent used React-Lazy